# What is the purpose of Bitcoin timestamps

Tags: bitcoin-core, timestamp

Why do we even need timestamps on the blocks?

Has it something to do with the consensus?

Comment: I think I found it out, but I'm not sure. I think timestamps are part of the difficulty adjustment of Bitcoin mining. To measure the time it took to mine the last x blocks. Can somebody confirm that?